# Why this jQuery CSS manipulation not working?

Tags: jquery, css

```
$("#submit_button").css("input.submit_button:hover","url()");
```

What I am trying to achieve is removing the background image url and when hovering and keep everything else intact.

Comment: What you trying to do here ?

Comment: @azio... Can you post related `HTML` to make it easy.

Answer (score 1):

`input.submit_button:hover` is selector not a css rule.

```
$("#submit_button").hover(function(){
   $(this).css('background-image','');
});
```

Comment: @azio does any other event is applied to this button...?

Answer (score 1):

Try a different approach

//css

```
 .includehover{
     background:url("yourfile");
    }
```

and give this class to your submit button

//jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit_button").mouseover(function(){            
              $(this).addClass('includehover');           

   });

$("#submit_button").mouseout(function(){            
                  $(this).removeClass('includehover');           

       });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Well i would suggest you to do that in css only. Have a css that gives background image to button and on hover don't provide the background image.

```
<input type = "submit" id = "sub" />

#sub {
background-image : url ('your url');
}

#sub:hover{
//No Background image attribute
}
```